# Qlik sense only show values on trend graph

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a trend graph line..and these values show as time differences for orders per customers

This is the sort of question to ask how to stop showing 0 however

This measure is worked out using an if statement.. within the if statement there is sum difference  between two time stamps.

if("CheckDate" < StartCheckDate , max({$<[Temperature]={'<=0'}>} CheckDate) - min({$<[Temperature]={'>0'}, CheckNumber = {1}>} CheckDate), max({$<[Temperature]={'<=0'}>} CheckDate) - min({$<[Temperature]={'>0'}, CheckNumber = {2}>} CheckDate))

However some customers are showing up as 00:00:00 how do I in the measure say don't show these customers.. that have 00:00:00

please help..

Comment: please add some data samples and your current calculation

Comment: Hi here is my measure (Relates to checking Fridge Temperatures)   if("CheckDate" < StartCheckDate , max({$<[Temperature]={'<=0'}>} CheckDate) -

min({$<[Temperature]={'>0'}, CheckNumber = {1}>} CheckDate), max({$<[Temperature]={'<=0'}>} CheckDate) -

min({$<[Temperature]={'>0'}, CheckNumber = {2}>} CheckDate))      please help

Comment: That's helpful context, but could you share a small sample of the actual data?

Comment: Hi the  CheckDate, StartCheckDate, all are formatted 01/01/2001 00:00:00     the CheckNumber just increments as 1, 2, 3  cant send sample of data sorry